# discord.js addRole to user

Tags: discord.js

Heyho!

Do you know how Im able to add a role to a user with a single command?

e. g: /accept @Kuezy
-> As soon as I send this command the bot should add the user the @Applicant role.

This is my code:

```
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(0x00FF00)
    .setTitle(`__Anmeldung bearbeitet | Angenommen!__`)
    .setDescription(`Lieber **${banMember}**,\nwir möchten dir mitteilen, das deine Anmeldung für unser Turnier angenommen wurde! Weitere Informationen folgen demnächst.\n\nSchönen Tag noch! :tada:`)
    .setFooter(`${colours.mainname}`, message.guild.iconURL())
banMember.send(embed)

var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "MyRole");
banMember.member.addRole(role);
```

:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really been around since older versions of Discord.JS, but I can tell you that none of your command's methods for adding a role to the user you're referring to exist anymore. Referring to your final line that says: `banMember.member.addRole(role);`.

In order to add a role to a user, you would simply have to get the user's member object then use the `.roles.add()` function to add the desired role:

```
message.guild.member(banMember).roles.add(role)
```

In addition, with the changes of v12, you're now required to cache the roles you're looking for in a `.find()` and `.get()` functions, hence why you should change your role finding function to the following:

```
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "MyRole");
```

You can read more about v12 changes here: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/12.0.0

Comment: Thanks for helping :D